# Finitely presented groups which are neither Hopfian nor cohopfian

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism, geometric-group-theory, group-presentation

Are there any examples of (preferably countable) finitely presented groups which are neither hopfian nor cohopfian? If so, is there a classification of such groups?

Comment: All finitely presented groups are countable (including finite).

Comment: Classification is hopeless, since for every finitely presented group $\Gamma$, the direct product $\Gamma\times BS(2,3)$ is neither Hopfian nor cohopfian. For $\Gamma$ directly indecomposable with trivial center, this decomposition is unique, so the direct product retrieves $\Gamma$.

Comment: Also, you could have observed that for every non-Hopfian finitely presented group $H$, the direct product $H\times\mathbf{Z}$ is clearly neither Hopfian nor cohopfian. This avoids relying on Derek's post, in which the injectivity of $(x,y)\mapsto (x^k,y)$ in $BS(2,3)$ is not completely trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Baumslag-Solitar groups, such as $G={\rm BS}(2,3) = \langle x,y \mid y^{-1}x^2y=x^3 \rangle$ are well-known examples of nonHopfian groups, and they are also not coHopfian, because they have isomorphic proper subgroups $H=\langle x^k,y \rangle$ for some $k>1$.

For example, when $k=5$, $|G:H| = 5$ and $H \cong G$.

Comment: I understand that B(1,m) is non cohopfian for m greater than 1, and that B(2,3) is not hopfian. It’s not obvious to me yet that B(2,3) is not cohopfian. Can you elaborate?